# Can't Access Server 2003 File Shares

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-10

Two workstations both running Windows 10 Pro 64. Very similar hardware configurations. Both going through same switch/network. Both members of the AD domain. Both logged in as same AD user. Both using same DNS servers, time is in sync.

Several 2008 - 2012 Servers, both workstations can access all these as expected.

Two windows-2003 Servers, Workstation1 cannot access either server, Workstation2 *can* access both as expected. All can ping each other.

Trying to get Workstation1 to see the shares on the 2003 servers.

`\\server` in Explorer returns "Windows cannot access \servera"

`net view \\server` returns "System error 53 has occurred."

Nothing stands out in the Event Viewer on the DC, 2003 server or the Workstation.

Any ideas as to where to begin troubleshooting Workstation1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you recently disabled SMBv1 on your workstations? 2003 only supports SMBv1, and with WannaCry many people disabled using it because it is insecure. If you've disabled SMBv1 on your clients, this would explain why. You can reverse the instructions found [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows) for testing on the Win10 workstation that can't reach the shares.